# Making a query using results from another query, with pointers - Android

Tags: parse-platform

having the following classes:

```
countryOffer:
-countryPointer
-offerPointer

Offer:
-objectId
-Title
-BusinessPointer
```

i want to select all offers in a specific country from countryOffer, then query the Offer class from the results in query1.

using Android.

EDIT:

What i have tried so far :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("countryOffer");
query1.include("countryPointer");
query1.include("offerPointer");
query1.whereEqualTo("countryPointer", country) //country is an object

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Offer");
query2.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "offerPointer", query1);
```

Comment: Dear Handsomeguy, kindly find my edit above for what i have tried so far.